# C# Two windows on desktop, one window fixed on right - fullscreen is smaller

Tags: c#, winforms

I creating desktop application in C#. I need fixed window same as [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71729.png) on right, and another windows have size in maximized mode in have width = fullwidth - myWindow.

How do you make it?

Im tried next code, it work good, but another fixed is fullscreen, and my app on top. I need windows fullscreen state as fullwidth - mywindow.

```
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    foreach (var scrn in Screen.AllScreens) {
        if (scrn.Bounds.Contains(Location)) {
            Height = scrn.WorkingArea.Height;
            Location = new Point(scrn.Bounds.Right - Width, scrn.Bounds.Top);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @HansPassant - I Dont access to left application, only for right application, for example Trillian application works this way. (as image)

Comment: Not the kind of detail to ever leave out of a question.  This requires code injection with SetWindowsHookEx() so you can change the response to the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message.  You cannot write such a hook in the C# language, C is the appropriate choice.